# Why codeigniter stopped working suddenly in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, server, frameworks

I have a codeigniter framework website and it was working fine for last 6 months.

Before two days the website is not loading. Sometimes it shows blank white screen or 503 error.
what will be the possible reasons?

I didn't changed any code or configuration at this time. It stopped working automatically.
All other websites in the server working fine.

Here is the `.htaccess`

```
#RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|download|dev|favicon\.ico|crossdomain\.xml|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php?/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: A 503 error should leave some details in the Apache logs. Look in your `/var/log/apache2` directory for any messages that point to the problem.

Comment: its in live server

Comment: Check the error log, It will give you an idea of what is causing the issue.

Comment: ERROR - 2021-07-30 18:00:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: Robotstxt/index
ERROR - 2021-07-30 18:00:26 --> 404 Page Not Found: Robotstxt/index
ERROR - 2021-07-30 18:00:27 --> 404 Page Not Found: App-adstxt/index

Comment: Which version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This Error is possibly caused bei either one of these:

- Server Root directory has changed

  - Check your **apache site configuration** (*Vhost config*)
- Your **config.php** configuration is wrong

  - Check your `base_url`
  - `base_url` should contain a FQDN and relative path to your site folder, eg: `http://example.com/website/`
- You are missing some **Routes**

  - Check your `application\config\routes.php` for missing routes

---

Further details about the issue could be found in `/var/log/apache/error.log` or similar *(like httpd instead of apache)* depending on your operating system

Comment: Hi, CI_VERSION = '3.1.11';

Comment: I updated my answer to match CodeIgniter version 3. Does it work?

Comment: no, actually its working in localhost but not in live server.

Comment: On the web, I recently somewhere stumbled upon the information that on localhost the `base_url` shall be empty. That is actually wrong. The documentation says on localhost use that as FQDN. like `http://localhost/mysite`

Comment: can you please check this, i updated the question. with the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605459/codeingeter-worked-in-local-server-but-not-in-lives-server

Comment: Please edit your question in this post and avoid open up more duplicates! Thanks. 
Have you tried my suggestions so far? Whats the results?