# Codeingeter worked in local server but not in lives server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

my codeingeter website worked in the live server for last 6 months and its suddenly stopped working. I checked the code with local server and its working there. What are the possible reasons.?

My PHP version is 7.3

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|css|js|icon|uploads|build|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Log file

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

ERROR - 2021-08-01 00:40:46 --> 404 Page Not Found: Robotstxt/index
ERROR - 2021-08-01 00:43:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: Phpinfophp/index
ERROR - 2021-08-01 00:43:25 --> 404 Page Not Found: _profiler/phpinfo
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['admin'] = "admin/home";
$route['contact'] = "home/contact";
$route['privacy'] = "home/privacy";
$route['terms'] = "home/terms";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

in my config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why codeigniter stopped working suddenly in server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68585743/why-codeigniter-stopped-working-suddenly-in-server)

Comment: No its not worked.

Comment: Is my code is correct?

Comment: Please dont open up duplicates intentionally!!